# WebException timeout Selenium Python, works first time through loop, then timesout

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, web-scraping, webdriver

I have a client that wants to web scrape this sketchy website and the loops works the first time, then the error occurs. Any help? I suggest not visiting the website, but hopefully the pays worth my time lol.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--incognito")
PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
URL = 'https://avbebe.com/archives/category/高清中字/page/5'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH, options=options)
driver.get(URL)

time.sleep(5)
Vid = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('entry-title')
for title in Vid:
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    time.sleep(5)
    WebDriverWait(title, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, 'a')))#where error occurs
    actions.double_click(title).perform()
    time.sleep(5)
    VidUrl = driver.current_url
    VidTitle = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="post-69331"]/h1/a').text
    try:
        VidTags = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('tags')
        for tag in VidTags:
            VidTag = tag.find_element_by_tag_name('a').text
        
    except NoSuchElementException or StaleElementReferenceException:
        pass
    
    with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding = "utf-8") as f:
        fieldnames = ['Title', 'Tags', 'URL']
        thewriter = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        thewriter.writeheader()
        thewriter.writerow({'Title': VidTitle, 'Tags': VidTag, 'URL': VidUrl})
    driver.back()
    driver.refresh()
print('done')
```

Error:

> ```
> WebDriverWait(title, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, 'a')))
>   File "C:\Users\Heage\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py",
> ```
>
> line 80, in until
> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: You aren't using a wait when you get the elements array.  This will work fine after a get(), but may not for a .back() or .refresh() Selenium waits for the page to load after a get()...  I would put the get() inside the loop instead of using back() and refresh().

Answer (score 3):

You are nearly there, just missing a few pieces.

Firstly, you are fetching all the links to videos, and then navigating in a loop.

```py
Vid = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('entry-title')
for title in Vid:
    # ...
    WebDriverWait(title, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, 'a')))
    # ...
    driver.back()
    driver.refresh()
```

What happens is that once the browser navigates to a different url, all of those elements become stale, i.e. they will throw an error when you try to click them as the browser no longer has a connection to the original elements.

So what you need to do is to read all the available links into a list and just access them using driver.get without the need to refresh the page

```py
link_elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('entry-title a')
links = {link_element.get_attribute('href') for link_element in link_elements}

for link in links:
    driver.get(link) # otherwise, stale elements
```

Next, once you open the page, you are searching for an element with an id.

```py
    VidTitle = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="post-69331"]/h1/a').text
```

However, you have to keep in mind that ids change from page to page, so your script is likely to fail here.
Instead, try to find classes that don't change. I took a look at the page and found that the video title has an  tag with a `entry-title` class, so I used that instead

```py
    VidTitle = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h1.entry-title').text
```

Working solution

```py
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

URL = 'https://avbebe.com/archives/category/高清中字/page/5'

driver.get(URL)

link_elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('entry-title a')
links = {link_element.get_attribute('href') for link_element in link_elements}

for link in links:
    driver.get(link)

    VidUrl = driver.current_url
    VidTitle = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h1.entry-title').text
    try:
        VidTags = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('tags')
        for tag in VidTags:
            VidTag = tag.find_element_by_tag_name('a').text

    except NoSuchElementException or StaleElementReferenceException:
        pass

    with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        fieldnames = ['Title', 'Tags', 'URL']
        thewriter = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        thewriter.writeheader()
        thewriter.writerow({'Title': VidTitle, 'Tags': VidTag, 'URL': VidUrl})

print('done')
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the line `driver.get(URL)` inside the loop. Remove `driver.back()` and `driver.refresh()`.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--incognito")
PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
URL = 'https://avbebe.com/archives/category/高清中字/page/5'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH, options=options)
driver.get(URL)

time.sleep(5)
Vid = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('entry-title')
for title in Vid:
    driver.get(URL)
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    time.sleep(5)
    WebDriverWait(title, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, 'a')))#where error occurs
    actions.double_click(title).perform()
    time.sleep(5)
    VidUrl = driver.current_url
    VidTitle = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="post-69331"]/h1/a').text
    try:
        VidTags = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('tags')
        for tag in VidTags:
            VidTag = tag.find_element_by_tag_name('a').text
        
    except NoSuchElementException or StaleElementReferenceException:
        pass
    
    with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding = "utf-8") as f:
        fieldnames = ['Title', 'Tags', 'URL']
        thewriter = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        thewriter.writeheader()
        thewriter.writerow({'Title': VidTitle, 'Tags': VidTag, 'URL': VidUrl})
    #driver.back()
    #driver.refresh()
print('done')
```